# How to get theme's info from wordpress.org/themes using api.wordpress.org?

Tags: plugins, themes, api, core

i am trying to get the html code of the description of a few themes from WordPress, i know this is possible to achieve in codecanyon, but can't get the hang of it in wordpress.org, i've read the api.wordpress.org documentation of theme and plugin section at https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API and was able to achieve this with plugins `https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/{slug}.json`, but themes aren't as clear. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the admin site you can use [themes_api()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/themes_api/)

```
$info = themes_api( 'theme_information', [ 'slug' => 'twentyten' ] );
echo esc_textarea( $info->sections['description'] );
```

but that's plain text, not HTML. The API request it generates is

https://api.wordpress.org/themes/info/1.2/?action=theme_information&request%5Bslug%5D=twentyten&request%5Blocale%5D=en_US&request%5Bwp_version%5D=5.3.2

You can see the parameters in there as multiple URL-encoded `request[key]` parameters.

Comment: It should be `$info->sections`, not `$info['section']` .. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Oops, yes. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for including both the themes_api request AND the related API URI. It's rare to see that connection made in such responses.